# PowerPoint presentation slide count from Python?

Tags: ms-office, python, powerpoint, com

Computing the sum page count of all my `.docx`, `.doc`, `.ppt`, `.pptx`, and `.pdf` files within a certain directory; but am a little confused at how to count PowerPoint slides.

Here's what I've tried:

```
from glob import glob
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader
import win32com.client

def pdf_page_count(filename):
    curr = open(filename, "rb")
    page_count = PdfFileReader(curr).getNumPages()
    curr.close()
    return page_count

def presentation_slide_count(filename):
    Application = win32com.client.Dispatch("PowerPoint.Application")
    Presentation = Application.Presentations.Open(filename)
    slide_count = len(Presentation.Slides)
    Presentation.Close()
    return slide_count

if __name__=='__main__':
    powerpoints = glob('*/*/*.pptx') + glob('*/*/*.ppt')
    documents = glob('*/*/*.docx') + glob('*/*/*.doc')
    pdf = glob('*/*/*.pdf')

    total_pdf_pages = sum([pdf_page_count(pdf) for pdf in pdf])
    total_docx_pages = 0
    total_powerpoint_slides = sum([presentation_slide_count(presentation)
                                   for presentation in powerpoints])

    print total_pdf_pages
    print total_powerpoint_slides
```

Additionally I have tried using [python-pptx](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.org) however I received lxml errors (so tried to build my own lxml; which errored out on iconv dependency trouble). Also since that only supports pptx, I would need to find an alternative method for ppt. PowerPoint 2013 x64 is installed, and I am using Python 2.7.4 x64.

#### How do I get total slide count from PowerPoint presentations using Python?

Comment: Tried `Presentation = Application.Presentations.Open(curr)` but that gave me this error:   `File "<COMObject <unknown>>", line 3, in Open
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None,
 0, -2147024773), None)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, figured out the answer.

It doesn't seem to like relative paths.

Adding this line to that function solves the problem:

```
from os import getcwd

filename = getcwd() + '//' + filename
```

Answer (score 1):

I think most easiest way is this.
In this way i can get total slide number.

```
from pptx import Presentation
prs = Presentation("path/example.pptx")
print(len(prs.slides))
```

Comment: When I tried this 7 years ago I couldn't install python-pptx, as referenced.